# Generate XML Invoice CS-Cart

Tags: php, xml, invoice, cs-cart

it's possible generate xml invoice into cs-cart? I want use DOMDocuments PHP to trasform HTML output into xml.

It's possible?

I have created a new template tpl into cs-cart and call from administrator. How can i use DOMDocuments? There is a plugin for do that?

Comment: do you already have the xml structure ?

Answer (score 0):

CS-Cart uses Twig for new versions (or Smarty for old ones) to transform invoice into HTML. XML is not supported and no ready plugin for that on https://marketplace.cs-cart.com

XML can be achieved by a custom solution only so please try yourself
If help is needed, please contact CS-Cart developers - https://marketplace.cs-cart.com/developers-catalog.html